# PHPUnit is giving me en error in asserting that it sees a value in a view

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

When I run a feature test that has 2 assertions (`assertSee`) PHPUnit only recognizes one (`title`) and not the `description`, even though I can clearly see it in `dd()` as a value that's been passed from the controller to the view.

The test:

```
/** @test */
    public function a_user_can_view_a_project(){
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $project = factory('App\Project')->create();
        $this->get('/projects/'.$project->id)->assertSee('title')->assertSee('description');
    }
```

The error:

```
Failed asserting that '<!doctype html>\n
<html lang="en">\n
<head>\n
    <meta charset="UTF-8">\n
    <meta name="viewport"\n
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">\n
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">\n
    <title>Document</title>\n
</head>\n
<body>\n
    <h3>Fugit molestias explicabo odio quis.</h3>\n
    <p>Quis aut consectetur quisquam a dolores voluptatibus. Quas quos quo iusto beatae sint voluptatem aspernatur. Molestiae repudiandae suscipit non vel. Ea quasi et eveniet.</p>\n
    Quis aut consectetur quisquam a dolores voluptatibus. Quas quos quo iusto beatae sint voluptatem aspernatur. Molestiae repudiandae suscipit non vel. Ea quasi et eveniet.\n
</body>\n
</html>\n
' contains "description".
```

The paragraph is the description it can't "see".

The dd():

```
.
.
.
#attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "First Project"
    "description" => "asdsdasdsadsadsadsadsa"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
.
.
.
```

Comment: your response doesn't contain the word "description", of course the test will not pass

Comment: by the way, the test recognizes "title" not because it's an attribute on the $project variable, but because there is a title tag on the response

Comment: if you want to know if a certain data has been sent to the view, i'll post a solution

Comment: @DjellalMohamedAniss You are absolutely right, I just started learning TDD so a rookie mistake.Now it works, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to test if a certain variable has been passed to your response ( a view in your case ) you need to use

```php
$response->assertViewHas("project",$project);
```

the `assertSee()` method only checks if the string passed as a parameter is a substring of the plain text response.